# Linear combination of a real-valued function and its inverse is analytic Implies the real-valued function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

If $u$ is a real-valued function on a disc $\Delta_R$ such that $u^{-1}+iu$ is analytic on $\Delta_R$, then does this imply that $u$ is analytic on $\Delta_R$?

I am actually trying to prove some other result and that result holds if the above statement is true.

Comment: what is $u^{-1}$, is it $\frac{1}{u} $ ? and $\Delta_R$ is an open disk of the complex plane ? and analytic means complex analytic or real analytic ? ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  This implies $u$ is constant on $\Delta_R$.

Comment: Or: The imaginary part of $(1/u+iu)^2$ is constant. (This leads to a proof with the minimal smoothness assumptions...)

Comment: Erm, never mind the bit about minimal snoothness, it's sort of obvious that $u$ is smooth.